# when click on add to cart it is not showing value after refreshing the page it is showing value

Tags: magento

> when click on add to cart it is not showing value after refreshing the
>   page it is showing value. Setlocation function is not working on list page

Comment: Magento admin and config question at this point as no programming related question was asked.  Those belong over in magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension for addign extra fee:

https://github.com/magentix/Fee

Comment: thanks it is working fine but can you please tell where i can change the label (fee) i am unable to find

Comment: You can change label from this file app/code/local/Magentix/Fee/Block/Sales/Order/Fee.php  Pls accept answer if it works for you

Comment: Please check this file as well : app/code/local/Magentix/Fee/Model/Sales/Quote/Address/Total/Fee.php

Comment: No i have try but it is showing same label "fee" i want change the label fee to fuel charges. I have updated line  'label'  => Mage::helper('fee')->__('Fuel charges'),

Comment: Its working fine for me. Change 'title' => Mage::helper('fee')->__('Fuel charges') in fetch fucntion in this file app\code\local\Magentix\Fee\Model\Sales\Quote\Address\Total\Fee.php